# Quill.register is not recognized as a function

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I have this Angular project which uses `ngx-quill` and I want to add the third party module, `quill-blot-formatter` to it.

I have installed `@types/quill` as a dev dependency to get rid of the TS linter errors and configured `tsconfig.json` to include `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`.

I have also added `quill.js` to `angular.json` as follows:

```
"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"
]
```

I am trying to register the module in `app.module.ts` but I get the following error on the browser console.

`quill.js:1122 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined`

This is my module registration code:

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import { BlotFormatter } from 'quill-blot-formatter';

Quill.register('modules/blotFormatter', BlotFormatter);
```

I have tried importing `Quill` in various ways (`* as Quill`, `* as QuillNamespace`) but nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing this:

`import { BlotFormatter } from 'quill-blot-formatter';`

to this:

`import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter';`

Apparently I didnt read the documentation properly :)

Answer (score 0):

try import Quill like this:

```
const Quill = require('quill')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [Github](https://github.com/Fandom-OSS/quill-blot-formatter)

> // from the index, which exports a lot of useful modules
> import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter';

> // or, from each individual module
> import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter/dist/BlotFormatter';

Individual module import helped me to solve the issue 
 `Issue: (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined).`